# diophantine equation $(1+\ldots+n)^k=1^l+\ldots+n^l$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Here's my equation I wrote and can't solve for over 3 months: $$(1+\ldots+n)^k=1^l+\ldots+n^l$$ in positive integers of course.

For any $n$ there are two obvious solutions: $k=l=1$ and $k=2,\ l=3$. Are there any others?

--

I tried to use some congruences, e.g. LHS is divisible by $n$ for odd $n$, but without any sensible result.

Comment: Fix $k=1$, you will get $l=1$, then fix $k=2$, you get $l=3$. Now for other solutions, you can prove that the LHS is always less than the RHS or RHS is less than the LHS, depending on which of $k$ or $l$ is greater

Comment: The leading $n$-dependence on LHS is $\left(\frac{n^{2}}{2}\right)^k$. On RHS, one can approximate the sum by an integral for large $n$, so the leading $n$-dependence is $\frac{n^{\ell+1}}{\ell+1}$. In order for the identity works for all $n$, a necessary condition is $2^k = \ell+1 = 2k$. There are only two possible candidates for $k$. Namely, $k = 1$ or $2$. Since both of them work, they are all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that $(1+2+3,\cdots+n)^1=(1^1+2^1+3^1,\cdots+n^1)$ and, for the sums of integers $I(n)$ and cubes $C(n)$

$$I(n)=(1+2+3,\cdots+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\implies (I(n))^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{2^2}$$
$$C(n)=(1^3+2^3+3^3,\cdots+n^3)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{2^2}$$
$$\therefore (1+2+3,\cdots+n)^2=(1^3+2^3+3^3,\cdots+n^3)$$

$$\text{In all cases }\quad (1+2+3,\cdots+n)^k=\frac{n^k(n+1)^k}{2^k}$$

The sums of the first $10$ powers are shown [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)
and I have worked out formulas up to $\sum_{x=1}^n x^{31}$.

None of these are even divisible by any power of $I(n)$ except for $l-3$ so I do not believe that are any other solutions.